# Using an exercises package to build lots of Math/Calculus exercise lists and tests

Tags: packages, exercises, workflow

I have been using the exercise.sty package for a while now, mostly to build exercise lists for my students. After a few months from when I started, the code became very complicated. Today, it is a living nightmare.

**But first, let me explain what I am using it for:**

I am building Math, Precalculus and Calculus exercise lists and tests for my students. They range from Second Degree Equations, Integration Techniques, Volumes by Disks, you name it. That said, each type of class I teach demands a separate material "filtered" so that it best fits the class: level of dificulty, topic, number of questions on the exercise list and so on.

**The problem is:** I have close to 500 exercises and I'm not sure where to start. I would like to start the right way, so that I don't fall into a hole (like I am today).

**My questions:**

- How can I type these exercises, the most efficient way possible, so that I can easily build these pdfs filled with the exercises that correspond to the given topic? Should I write these 500 exercises in a single .tex file?
- Is there a package that allows two different types of solution for the same question? Let me explain this one: sometimes I just want to show the final solution, and sometimes the complete (worked-out) solution.
- Some of my students are native from US so is there a way to, for the same exercise, create two (or more) different descriptions and answers (one in Portuguese and one in English)?
- Lest's say at one point I reach 10,000 exercises. Can I use a single .tex file with all of them to build, for example, an exercise list with 40 "quadratic equations" exercises? In other words: use the "filters" or "labels" from these packages to make this filtering process?

I understand that these packages' capabilities are HUGE so I would love if someone could shine a light in a very efficient approach.

Thank you.

PS.: If I wasn't very clear on my explanations please let me know.

Comment: With 500+ exercises I think you need a serious workflow that goes beyond TeX. Probably each exercise in a separate file, with tags and a search mechanism to find the ones you want, and glue them together. Maybe even a database solution (might be possible with TeX). I think you should ask the two kinds of answers question separately from this one, with an MWE.

Comment: There are ways to combine different versions.  For example, the macro \figurename defaults to "Figure", but can be reset (by Bable) to the appropriate word in the chosen language.

Comment: @EthanBolker I've tried a few options always with one exercise per .tex file, and that's one of the reasons the whole thing turned into a nightmare. I am wondering if I am missing something: one of these packages may have a feature that, when used properly, makes the process work like a charm

Comment: Don't know how well it would work with that many entries, but you could try [using datatooltk to store the questions](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/datatoolexam.shtml), although with 10,000 exercises as @EthanBolker mentioned, you'd be better off using a database solution (which can be integrated with TeX using `datatooltk` in batch mode).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I understand that you are the developer of datatoolkt is that correct? If so, can I attribute two answers for the same question (for example, when I only want to show the solution, or when I want to show the complete explanation of the solution)?

Comment: 1) is opinion based question you can write all  exercises in  a single .tex  you can make file by exercise or file by topic. for 2) and 3) the  answer is yes 4)  whatever  choice  you make (single file or multiple) yes you can do what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe I'm being naïve, but why don't you just use a directory hierarchy. `problems`, `problems/algebra`, `problems/algebra/beginners`, `problems/algebra/cuttingedge`, `problems/analysis`, `problems/analysis/complex/intermediate` etc. There really isn't a need for a database unless you want to combine questions in different ways such that there are no natural joints. But here the divisions are just that natural ones. [If you cover several topics in a course, you might prefer to have level be the higher directory level and topic the lower one. Otherwise, it probably makes no odds.]

Comment: Maybe the [``@EASE``](http://www.acrotex.net/atease_index.php) package?  The short description: ``@EASE`` stands for AcroTeX Exam Assembly System Environment. ``@EASE`` allows educators to assemble a database of questions. With the ``@EASE`` control panel, the educator opens appropriate database files (PDF-files), selects questions of interest to builds an exam, which is a LaTeX source file, consisting of the questions selected. ``@EASE`` requires Acrobat Pro 7.0 or later to execute some JavaScript not available in Adobe Reader. Disclaimer: I've not used it.

Comment: @bru1987 Yes, that's right. You could just define a boolean, e.g. `\newif\ifcomplete` and then just have `\ifcomplete extra stuff\fi` within the answer. Alternatively, with the database approach have an extra field for the complete answer (depends how different the complete answer is from the abridged answer).

Comment: @cfr I understand your approach, that's what I've been currently using, but please trust me that this turns into a nightmare in a really short time!

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I see. The second option you mentioned seems like it will work perfectly. Thank you for your input, I appreciate that. I may have found what I've been looking for.

Comment: You might look at webwork. That system allows you to use their exercises (1000s of them) and add your own. It gives latex output, or html output, and uses a sophisticated language (Perl) so that you can give online tests using your problems. You can also easily share your problems with other instructors who use webwork.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since your question is about storing, maintaining and referencing a large set of exercises (potentially in the order of 10,000), I'm going to concentrate on that, so the style here is very basic.

It's possible to define conditionals using `\newif` (or through commands provided by packages such as [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)). For example:

```
\newif\ifsolutions
\newif\ifcomplete
```

These default to false, but can be switched on:

```
\solutionstrue
\completetrue
```

It's also useful to provide syntactic commands to mark the solution. For example:

```
\newcommand{\solutionname}{Solution}
\newcommand{\solution}{\par\textbf{\solutionname}:\par}
```

As has been mentioned in one of the other answers, it's also possible to use environments and the [`comment`](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment) package. For multilingual support, the caption hooks can be used to redefine `\solutionname` as appropriate. For example:

```
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}

\addto\captionsUSenglish{%
  \renewcommand\solutionname{Solution}%
}
```

Now an exercise can be written using these commands. For example:

```
$y = \sin(2x)$
\ifsolutions
 \solution
 \ifcomplete
  Intermediate steps, further details etc.
 \fi
 $y' = 2\cos(2x)$
\fi
```

Environments provide a more LaTeXy feel, but let's concentrate on storing and accessing the questions.

The simple method, which has already been suggested, is to put each question in a separate file and load it with `\input`. For example, if this exercise is in the file `exercises/calculus/easy/dsin.tex` then the following MWE works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifsolutions
\newif\ifcomplete

\solutionstrue
\completetrue

\newcommand{\solutionname}{Solution}
\newcommand{\solution}{\par\textbf{\solutionname}:\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \input{exercises/calculus/easy/dsin}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This is a relatively generic method, which can easily be translated to other TeX formats. For example, the Plain TeX equivalent is:

```
\newif\ifsolutions
\newif\ifcomplete

\solutionstrue
\completetrue

\def\solutionname{Solution}
\long\def\solution{\par{\bf\solutionname}:\par}

\newcount\questionnum

\long\def\question{%
 \par
 \advance\questionnum by 1\relax
 \number\questionnum.
}

\question \input exercises/calculus/easy/dsin

\bye
```

The problem is that, although this structure is fine for a small number of questions, it can become unmanageable for 10,000. I mentioned [`datatooltk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatooltk) in the comments, which can read and write `.dbtex` files (`datatool`'s internal format), but I don't recommend using this format directly. These files just contain LaTeX code that defines the internal registers and control sequences used by [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) to store the required data. There's no compression and it takes up a huge amount of resources. The `datatooltk` application works better as an intermediary that can pull filtered, shuffled or sorted data from external sources in a way that can easily be input in the document. (See the [`datatool` performance page](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/datatool-performance.shtml) that compares build times for large databases.)

There are switches, such as `--shuffle` or `--sort`, which instructs `datatooltk` to shuffle or sort the data *after* it's been pulled from the data source. This uses Java, which is more efficient than TeX, but if the data is stored in a SQL database, it's even more efficient to include these steps in the actual `--sql` switch. (Currently, `datatooltk` is only configured for MySQL, but it may be possible to use something else if the necessary `.jar` file can be added to the class path.)

[SQL databases can be optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39331) to improve performance. Suppose you want to randomly select 20 questions from 500. How do you perform that selection in LaTeX? First you'd need to use the shell to find out all the available files (or have an index file that can be parsed). Then you need to shuffle the list. That will take a while to do with TeX. It's more efficient to do this with SQL. (See, for example, [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4329396).)

If you decide to use SQL, the next thing to consider is the table structure.

- You'll need a unique id field. With this you'll be able to specifically select certain questions rather than have a random selection. (An [auto increment primary key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) is best.)
- A field containing the question. (Let's call it `Question`.)
- A field containing the brief answer. (Let's call it `Answer`.)
- A field containing the extended answer. (Let's call it `ExtendedAnswer`.)
- A field identifying the difficulty level. (Let's call it `Level`.) This could be an integer (1 = easy) or an enumeration (`easy`, `medium`, `hard`).
- A field identifying the topic. (Let's call it `Topic`.) An enumeration is probably the simplest type (for example, `calculus`, `settheory`).

I'm not quite sure about the language. There are two approaches that I can think of: have fields for the other language (For example, `QuestionPortuges`, `AnswerPortuges` and `ExtendedAnswerPortuges`) or have a separate entry for the question in a different language with an extra field for the language.

So the above exercise example, could have

- `Question` => `$y = \sin(2x)$`
- `Answer` => `$y' = 2\cos(2x)$`
- `ExtendedAnswer` => `Intermediate steps, further details etc. \[y' = 2\cos(2x)\]`
- `Level` => `1`
- `Topic` => `calculus`
- `Language` => `english` or `ExtendedAnswerPortuges` => `Passos intermédios, etc. \[y' = 2\cos(2x)\]`

Note that this doesn't include the syntactic command `\solution` or the conditionals `\ifsolutions` and `\ifcomplete`, which makes it easier to arrange the various parts of the question and answer.

It may be that some exercises require a particular package (such as `amsmath` or `graphicx`), so perhaps there could also be a field for the required packages. For example `Packages` => `graphicx,amsmath`.

Any images or verbatim text must be stored outside the database somewhere on the file system. They could be on TeX's path or the database table could have a field with a list of external resources or the question/answer could simply use the full path.

The `datatooltk` call can be done before the LaTeX run or using the shell escape. There's also a `datatooltk` rule for [`arara`](http://ctan.org/pkg/arara) users. Let's suppose, I use `datatooltk` to pull a random selection of questions and save the results in a file called `exercises.dbtex`. This can then be loaded in the document using:

```
\DTLloaddbtex{\exercisedb}{exercises.dbtex}
```

If the data includes the `Packages` field, you can make sure all the required packages are loaded by adding the following to the preamble:

```
\DTLforeach*{\exercisedb}{\Packages=Packages}
{\DTLifnullorempty{\Packages}{}{\usepackage{\Packages}}}
```

In the main part of the document:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\DTLforeach*{\exercisedb}% data base
{\Question=Question,\Answer=Answer,\ExtendedAnswer=ExtendedAnswer}% assignment list
{%
  \item \Question
  \ifsolutions
   \solution
   \ifcomplete
    \ExtendedAnswer
   \else
     \Answer
   \fi
  \fi
}
\end{enumerate}
```

Further reading: [Using the datatool Package for Exams or Assignment Sheets](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/datatoolexam.shtml)

Comment: Thank you for the input Nicola, your solution and your package are exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the awesome input. Best Regards!

Comment: I think that the second `"\Answer"` sould be "Answer" at the begining of the main document code. Excellent work by the way!

Comment: @mac Yes, you're right. I've fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

What I did for my students was this.

1. I seperated all my exercises in different folders by subject. Each folder is named like this "1_package, 2_package" etc.
2. Each exercise in any folder is numbered by the name of the folder and the number of the exercise. For example "3_294" is the 294th exercise in the 3rd folder.
3. In order to remember the content of each folder I made a list that shows what's inside. Let's say 1-> Integration, 2->Limits etc.
4. I created the following (mwe) `Test.tex` template:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \newcommand{\exercise}[2]{\input{#1_package/#1_#2.tex}} 
  \begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item \exercise{1}{3}
  \item \exercise{2}{28}
  \item \exercise{3}{294}
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{document}
```

The result for example could be like this:
[image]

But I was also concerned about how could I select the proper exercise among 500+ exercises. Thus I created a list of them using the following code in a `Database.tex` file:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=Integration.\arabic*.]
\foreach \t in {1,...,"number of the last ex. in folder 1"}{\item\exercise{1}{\t}}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=Differential Equations.\arabic*.]
\foreach \x in {1,...,"number of the last ex. in folder 2"}{\item\exercise{2}{\x}}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=Limits.\arabic*.]
\foreach \y in {1,...,"number of the last ex. in folder 3"}{\item\exercise{3}{\y}}
\end{enumerate}
```

...............
E.T.C.
The output is a list of all my exercises in all of my folders. Maybe printing that list will be more helpful in choosing the exercises.

---

### **EDIT 24/11/2021**

---

I would like introduce [**DataTeX**](https://github.com/CSMathematics/DataTex). It is a program for creating and managing LaTeX files databases as well as LaTeX document databases. I will give a brief description for each of these 2 database types:

**1. Files database**
[image]

- A LaTeX file can be a definition, a theorem, an exercise or any other
  file type that anyone needs to store and add in a document. Each time
  we dreate a file we can choose tags like filetype, topic, chapter,
  section and many more, which will then be used to filter our database
  and easily find the file we need.
  [image]
- Exercises can be solved and many solutions can be stored for each file.
  [image]
- The files can be added, removed and edited.

**2. Document database**
[image]

- In DataTeX we can create LaTeX document databases, where each document can be filtered by type such as Exams, Notes etc.
  [image]
- In these documents we can add the files that we mentioned above by simply selecting them from the database table.
  [image]
- If a document contains exercises then we can create a solution document almost automatically.
  [image]

Many Files and Document databases can be created. The database engine is Sqlite. It is written in C++.

The program uses a very simple pdf viewer and a minimal LaTeX compiler for the files that can run PdfLaTeX,LaTeX,XeLaTeX,PythonTeX,Asymptote and BibTeX.(PdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and PythonTeX have been tested and work fine but many improvments are needed)

**DISCLAIMER**

I'm not a professional programmer so the code might be quite messy and the software still needs a lot of work untill it is fully functionable. I can say that a 70%-80% is ready and the basic functions I mentioned above work fine.

For the moment it is only available for linux with Texlive installed.

I don't know how to make the software ready to build and installed in linux, so qt creator (5.15.2) is the only way I know so far to compile it for the 1st time.

Any help and contribution is most welcome!!

Comment: That is a neat idea. I'm going to use it.

Comment: How it works I have not understood. :-((((( I use Windows but it is "only available for linux with Texlive installed".

Comment: I hope that I will be able to upload a brief documentation or a short video presentation as soon as possible. Unfortunatelly the software is only available for Linux at the moment because I haven't yet managed to compile it and make it available for windows also. I need help and contribution in this part in order for a Windows version to be available.

Comment: I hope this will help a little: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWkXTwT7L2Y

Answer (score 1):

Here;'s a proof of concept solution for the easy parts of your question - the second and third bullet points.

You could easily make it more elaborate, formatting and numbering exercises, adding keywords and tags. I don't think it makes sense to do that until the overall project structure is set.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{comment}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%This material should be in a preamble  
%
\newenvironment{exercise}
{}{}

\newenvironment{portuguese}
{}{}

\newenvironment{english}
{}{}

\newenvironment{final}
{}{}
\newenvironment{workedout}
{}{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This part can be in a master file for one handout that inputs the
% preamble and then the exercises for that handout.

% \documentclass{whatever}
% \input{preamble}

% decide what appears in the document

\excludecomment{english}
%\includecomment{english}

%\excludecomment{portuguese}
\includecomment{portuguese}

\excludecomment{final}
%\includecomment{final}

%\excludecomment{workedout}
\includecomment{workedout}

\begin{document}

General description for this worksheet.

%\input{ex1}
%\input{ex2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% for each exercise in its own file
% \documentclass{standalone} 
\begin{exercise}

\begin{english}
This is an exercise.
\end{english}
\begin{portuguese}
Exercise text in Portuguese.
\end{portuguese}

\begin{final}

Solution here, no details. Could switch between English and Portuguese
easily, as above.
\end{final}

\begin{workedout}
Complete worked out solution. Could be multilingual.
\end{workedout}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why would you invent new environments for the different languages rather than using Babel or Polyglossia or ...? Are you sure those names won't conflict if the user is using one of those packages?

Comment: @cfr You're right (as usual). My goal was just to show that the easy parts of the OPs problem could be solved, so others could focus on the hard parts. I used what I knew, so not the tools designed for multilanguage support. If you'd like to improve my answer, feel free. Or post your own and I'll cheerfully delete mine.