# Exam class question library

Tags: exam, database

I would like to create a question archive, and have a system to include selected questions in an exam document. I started using Latex last year, and made all my tests, homeworks and exams in Latex since. The questions are in the documents, with their solutions, but I would like to reuse the questions and solutions in other exams, without having to search through previous tests.

Does anyone have suggestions for this? Ideally, I would like to tag the questions with some properties, like easy or hard, and a code referring to the end terms from government, in order to have a balanced exam.

Comment: It will require some tweaking, but the `exsheets` package might be just what you need. Look at Section 15 "Selectively Include Questions from External Files" from the manual, http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets

Comment: Possibly [Using an exercises package to build lots of Math/Calculus exercise lists and tests](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331594/106162) covers the same sort of ground.

Comment: What you really want is to organize your source code.  Some editors (e.g. TexnicCenter) have a "Search in Files"  feature which can locate every occurrence  of a given keyword in your tex library.