# How to generate question paper from question bank database?

Tags: texlive, database

I have a question bank(hard copy). Each question has multiple attributes(chapter, topics, year, difficulty, marks, no of choice etc.)

I will generate different types(by topics, by chapter, by marks) of question for my students. So, I decide to make a mysql database for those questions from hard copy so that I can generate a question easily.

Now, I need a latex tool by which I can retrieve question from mysql database and generate question paper.

There are two tasks 1st is retrieve the data from database and 2nd is showing these in special question format.

Comment: You can use LuaLaTeX. Just install a module for db access (see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_database_access.htm)) and then use it for questions.

Comment: You could use `datatooltk` and `datatool` ([example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/datatoolexam.shtml)).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3697 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331594

Comment: Can [SQLTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sqltex) fulfill my requirements?