# Students text from a database

Tags: text, gradetable

I was searching the internet for a package able to generate a student's
exam from a database (e.g. below) taking randomly questions (and
shuffling the options, creating a table with the correct ones) but I was not able to find such a package.

Does someone know such a package?

All the best,

Rogério

---

Question one: some nice text

a) Answer a - Correct

b) Answer b - Wrong

c) Answer c- Wrong

d) Answer d- Wrong

e) Answer e- Wrong

Question two: some nice text

a) Answer a - Correct

b) Answer b - Wrong

c) Answer c- Wrong

d) Answer d- Wrong

e) Answer e- Wrong

and so on....

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331594/using-an-exercises-package-to-build-lots-of-math-calculus-exercise-lists-and-tes/332025#332025). It might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. You can use `examdesign`+`RndTexExams` where you can create and graduate randomized exams.
See this link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RndTexExams/vignettes/rte-vignette_creating_exams.html and the example 
into this link: https://gist.github.com/msperlin/ef1b93a8eb9026ba5e9a

```
\documentclass[10pt]{examdesign}

% loads all necessary packages (feel free to customize for your needs)

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{totpages}
\usepackage[margin=0.9in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\usepackage{framed}

\SectionFont{\large\sffamily}
\Fullpages
\ContinuousNumbering
\DefineAnswerWrapper{}{}
\NumberOfVersions{1}

%\ShortKey      % shows a short key answer sheet
\NoKey          % Print key ?

\NoRearrange    % Random arrange with latex? (leave it UNCOMMENTED, R will do all of the dirty work)

\newcommand{\myversion}{} % this line is very important as it locates and allows the printed test to show the number of  the test (DONT DELETE IT)

% You probably want to change the next lines

\newcommand{\UniName}{Name of my University} 
\newcommand{\DeptName}{My Department} 
\newcommand{\ClassName}{My Class Name} 
\newcommand{\MyName}{Author: My name}
\newcommand{\ExamName}{Exam Name: Version \myversion}
\newcommand{\TermName}{Current Term}

\rfoot{Random test \# \myversion}

\begin{document}

\begin{examtop}

% detais of the exam (you should probably edit this!)
\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Large \UniName} \\
    \textbf{\Large \DeptName} \vspace{0.5cm}  \\
    \textbf{\Large \ClassName} \\
    \textbf{\Large \MyName} \\
    \textbf{\Large \ExamName } \\
    \textbf{\Large \TermName}
 \end{center}

\vspace{1cm}
Name: \rule{4in}{.4pt}  \quad  \noindent Card:\enspace\hrulefill

%\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{2pt}

\vspace{1cm}

\small

\begin{framed}

Instructions for this test:

\begin{itemize}

    \item Make sure you finish before the end of the exam time

    \item There is only one correct answer in all multiple choice questions

    \item Don't cheat!

\end{itemize}

\vspace{0.5cm}

{\large \emph{Good Luck!}}
\end{framed}

\begin{framed}
    Instructions on how to use RndTexExams (DELETE THIS IN THE FINAL VERSION)
    \begin{itemize}

        \item The switch statements for the text of the questions, including main text and answers are defined as @{Text for version 1}|{Text for version 2}@. For each question, fell free to define as many versions as needed.

        \item You can define the right answer in each version of the test by assigning the character [!] or [ver] in the right answer for version ver. See the rest of the file for examples.


    \end{itemize}

\end{framed}

\end{examtop}


\vspace{1cm}

\begin{multiplechoice}[resetcounter=no,  examcolumns=1]

\begin{question}

    Which one is the correct answer in the next five alternatives?

    \choice{Choice 1}

    \choice{Choice 2}

    \choice{Choice 3}

    \choice{Choice 4}

    \choice[!]{Choice 5 - CORRECT}

\end{question}

\begin{question}

    Consider the following statements:

    \begin{enumerate}[I]
        \item The color of the sky is generally @{blue}|{red}@

        \item R has a @{high}|{low}@ number of packages for empirical research in Finance

        \item Microsoft word is @{better}|{worse}@ than latex for creating structured documents
    \end{enumerate}

    Are correct:

    \choice{[1] I and II}

    \choice{II and III}

    \choice{I, II and III}

    \choice{[2] Only III}

    \choice{Only I}

\end{question}


\begin{question}

    Which of the next answers do you think is the correct one? (there are three versions of this question. This is version @{1}|{2}|{3}@)

    \choice{Choice 1 - Incorrect in all versions}

    \choice{[1] Choice 2 - @{Correct in version 1}|{Incorrect in version 2}|{Incorrect in version 3}@}

    \choice{[3] Choice 3 - @{Incorrect in version 1}|{Incorrect in version 2}|{Correct in version 3}@}

    \choice{Choice 4 - Incorrect in all versions}

    \choice{[2] Choice 5 - @{Incorrect in version 1}|{Correct in version 2}|{Incorrect in version 3}@}

\end{question}


\begin{question}

    Consider the following statements:

    \begin{enumerate}[I]
        \item Latex is @{good}|{bad}@ for structured documents

        \item Working with R and latex is a @{good}|{bad}@ choice for writing up and marking tests

        \item We @{love}|{hate}@ R

    \end{enumerate}

    Which statements are true?

    \choice{I e II}
    \choice{[1] I, II e III}
    \choice{Only III}
    \choice{I e III}
    \choice{[2] None of the other options}

\end{question}


\end{multiplechoice}


\end{document}
```

You can see another link: http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/eqexam.html or https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Typing_exams_in_LaTeX.

Comment: If you're happy check with the V green my answer. Thank you. We are here to help each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have look to the `esami` package, based on D. P. Story's `acrotex` package, which has all the features you want.